# How to pass a pageable null from a webService?

Tags: java, spring-boot

So I have a backEnd with java and spring boot, the problem is occurring in pageable of the following code from a webservice:

```
    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Page<AreaDto> search(
                @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
                @RequestParam(value = "codOrg", required = false) Long codOrg,
                @RequestParam(value = "codCar", required = false) Long codCar,
                Pageable pageable
) {
    ...
    ...
```

but if I do not pass the pageable as parameter or pass with the itens ​​of the pageable all set to null it always comes with default values, which are as follows:
.

Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort: null]
.

for example, if I call this webservice in any of the ways below, the pageable will always come mounted with default values

```
    resources/areas?page=null&size=null&sort=null
    resources/areas?page=0&size=0
    resources/areas
    resources/areas?name='test'
```

So that's it, how to call this webservice with a pageable null?

Comment: Have you tried using Optional<Pageable> pageable syntax for the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

What about implementing your own [PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/web/config/PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer.html)? If no arguments are provided, just return null?